# Capturing text of function call in r

Tags: r, function, call, quoting

I have a function rts() which generates a couple of different charts and displays the raw data they are based on.  The argument is another function, raw_data(), which filters a larger data set based on the arguments to the raw_data() function.  For example:

```
rts(raw_data(compound.list=c('xylene','hexane','unknown'), days=20))
```

All of this works just fine, but I want to capture the text of the function call to rts() use as a subtitle in one of the charts produced by the rts() function.  I've tried using enexpr(raw_data) to capture this, eg:

```
rts <- function(raw_data) {
  func_call<- paste0('rts(', enexpr(raw_data), ')')
  ... some code that generates charts etc ...
   }
```

But when I use the func_call string as a subtitle, it just comes out as "rts(raw_data)", whereas I want it to be able to capture the function call to raw_data() within the rts() function call.  That is, I want the subtitle of the chart to be exactly what was typed to generate the chart: 'rts(raw_data(compound.list=c('xylene','hexane','unknown'), days=20))'

Answer (score 0):

By the time I was ready to hit send on the question, I found a workable solution.  I went ahead and posted it anyway in case it is useful to anyone else.

It turns out that the object returned by enexpr() is of type 'language', whatever that means.  I was able to convert it to a character string using rlang::list2(), which got me the result I was looking for:

```
func_call<- paste0('rts(', paste0(rlang::list2(enexpr(raw_data))), ')')
```

This gives the exact text that was typed in, even when the raw_data() function call had another function call embedded within it eg:

> rts(raw_data(compound.list=search_compounds('terp'),days=20))

Comment: If you want to read about: https://adv-r.hadley.nz/quasiquotation.html

Comment: The base R functions to do this are `substitute` to get the expression passed to an argument, and `deparse` to turn the result into a character string, so `deparse(substitute(raw_data))` would give you what you wanted.